# jQuery custom core : use just what you need

Tags: jquery, optimization, performance, minify

As you may have guessed, I'm trying to speed up page loading on my website.
So since I Don't use most of jQuery's functions, I thought that I could use a "lighter" version.

Is there an easy way to get your custom version of jQuery (like with jQuery UI)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427858/how-to-customize-jquery)

Comment: Kind of, I haven't seen this question. Should I delete mine ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are looking at the wrong place to solve your problem. In most cases [minified JQuery from a CDN like google](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery) doesn't take much of your time. I would look at other things that are taking up time onload.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense, I'll try to focus on other things to speed up loading